# Swift : Trying to have animation occur one by one

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have four funcs with an animation for a specific `UIImageView` and I have set those funcs inside an array. I wanted the animation to occur one by one when I tap on a button, but they all happen at the same time.

How do I make it so that when the animation is done, then the next animation starts, and all 4 are animated?

CODE:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.initAdMobBanner()

    funcArray = [self.animatePattern1, self.animatePattern2, self.animatePattern3, self.animatePattern4]

    createArrays()
    score = 0
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    highScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("HighScore")

    tapButton.hidden = false
    goButton.hidden = true
}

@IBAction func tapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tapButton.hidden = true
    self.main.shuffleInPlace()
    print(self.main)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: NSTimeInterval(1.0), options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
        self.funcArray[self.main[0] - 1]()
        }) { _ in

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: NSTimeInterval(2.0), options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
                self.funcArray[self.main[1] - 1]()
                }, completion: { _ in

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: NSTimeInterval(3.0), options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
                        self.funcArray[self.main[2] - 1]()
                        }, completion: { _ in

                            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: NSTimeInterval(4.0), options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
                                self.funcArray[self.main[3] - 1]()
                                }, completion: { _ in
                                    self.goButton.hidden = false
                            })
                    })
            })
    }

}


func createArrays() {
    self.p1.backgroundColor = self.colors[1]
    self.p2.backgroundColor = self.colors[2]
    self.p3.backgroundColor = self.colors[3]
    self.p4.backgroundColor = self.colors[4]
}

func animatePattern1() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.p1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.p1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })}
}

func animatePattern2() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.p2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.p2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })}
}

func animatePattern3() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.p3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.p3.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })}
}

func animatePattern4() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.p4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.p4.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of different arrays is hard to follow, and your calling of a function that has an animation block from inside an animation block is atypical. You should try simplifying. You can say something like:

```
@IBAction func tapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tapButton.hidden = true
    self.main.shuffleInPlace()
    print(self.main)
    self.animatePattern1()
}

   func animatePattern1() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
                self.p1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.p1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.animatePattern2()
        })
    }

    func animatePattern2() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
            self.p2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.p2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.animatePattern3()
        })
    }

    func animatePattern3() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
            self.p3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.p3.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                self.animatePattern4()
        })
    }

    func animatePattern4() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
            self.p4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.p4.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })
    }
```

This will probably break other functionality but it will do the animation in sequence. If you want to be able to perform the animations independently you can just add a Bool parameter to each like so:

```
func animatePattern1(inSequence:Bool) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
                self.p1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.p1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                if inSequence {
                    self.animatePattern2(inSequence)
                }
        })
    }

    func animatePattern2(inSequence:Bool) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .Autoreverse, animations: {
            self.p2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.p2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
                if inSequence {
                    self.animatePattern3(inSequence)
                }
        })
    }

    //etc.
```